# Cannot push into session array after unset command

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a session array into which I want to push a series of strings, one by one. I'm doing it like this:

```
$oldSession = $this->session->userdata('mySession');
array_push($oldSession, $data);
$this->session->set_userdata('mySession', $oldSession);
```

After some cycles, now I want to clear this array so I can start the entire process again. For this I use:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('mySession');
```

Unfortunately, after this, I cannot use my previous code as `array_push($oldSession, $data);` requires `$oldSession` to be in the form of an array. I even tried the following:

```
if (!$oldSession) {
   $this->session->set_userdata('mySession', $data);
}
```

but this add the data as a `string` into the session and in the next loop, I cannot use `array_push` again.

Hope there is an easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: `$this->session->set_userdata('mySession', array($data));`

Comment: @splash58 Bravo sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before pushing, check if it's an array. if not, create an empty one

```
$oldSession = $this->session->userdata('mySession');
if (!is_array($oldSession)) $oldSession = array();
array_push($oldSession, $data);
$this->session->set_userdata('mySession', $oldSession);
```

Comment: I did not know how flexible `array()` is. Thanks.

Comment: As said by @splash58 `$this->session->set_userdata('mySession', array($data));` also works perfectly.

Comment: no it does not. it will make the array deeper and deeper each time this code is called ;)

Comment: I mean the operator inside the IF :)

Comment: That's where I put it. Works perfectly for me.